# Concatenate PDF files and insert a page into a PDF File

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, concatenation

I’ve got this new task of creating a web app (I will use Asp.net + C#):
•   The customer gives us an X number of PDF files everyday (x will be different from day to day)
•   My application will need to take this PDF files and insert a blank page after page #3 (not each 3 pages, just after page #3) of each PDF file and then concatenate all of those PDF files them into one large PDF file.
I was thinking about using Aspose, since it seems like it can concatenate pdf files, but i will have to check if it can also insert a page inside a pdf file.

Are there any other plugins , webservices, code behind  or even a technique that you are aware that does just that ?

Comment: iTextSharp is a great open source tool for this.  I use it for almost the exact same thing in our environment.  Specifically you should look at the `PdfReader` and `PdfConcatenate` Classes.  [Get it on Source Forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Comment: Thanks @Evanlewis... The thing i dont like about iText is that they dont have good examples... you need to buy their book to understand all it can do... and even easy stuff like split and concatenate, they have some weird examples...

Comment: No problem.  I know the iText website is lacking in good documentation and examples, but Stack Overflow is FULL of great examples.  Search PDF Concatenate with iTextSharp and you will see a great deal of good examples.  You will need a fairly good understanding of C# to use the library properly though.  Generally you will be working with Input/Output files and end up deleting what you don't need after you have split/merged the documents.  There are alot of good PDF libraries but the iText functionality is definitely the best free option I know of.  If you want to pay money, go with Quick PDF.

Comment: I don't think Aspose is free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task can be accomplished quite easily with [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/).

Here is the code that merges files while adding blank pages after third page in each file.

```
public static void insertBlanksAndMerge()
{
    string[] filesToMerge = { "file1.pdf", "file2.pdf" };
    
    // open first file
    int pagesBefore = 0;
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(filesToMerge[0]))
    {
        pdf.InsertPage(pagesBefore + 3);

        // append all other documents
        for (int i = 1; i < filesToMerge.Length; i++)
        {
            pagesBefore = pdf.PageCount;

            pdf.Append(filesToMerge[i]);
            pdf.InsertPage(pagesBefore + 3);
        }

        pdf.Save(@"out.pdf");
    }
}
```

Please note that `PdfDocument` constructor and `Append` method can use not only file names but also streams and byte buffers.

More samples available [on GitHub](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples).

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the library.

Comment: Can I use it for a freeware application for free.

Comment: @Foreever Unfortunately, no. The library is no longer free even for freeware applications.

Comment: PdfDocument does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments.  Also, "InsertPage" doesn't exist in PdfDocument... am I using the wrong reference?  This isn't iTextSharp?

Answer (score 1):

I used iTextsharp to combine pdf files. This is the code I used.

```
string[] lstFiles=new string[3];
    lstFiles[0]=@"C:/pdf/1.pdf";
    lstFiles[1]=@"C:/pdf/2.pdf";
    lstFiles[2]=@"C:/pdf/3.pdf";

    PdfReader reader = null;
    Document sourceDocument = null;
    PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
    PdfImportedPage importedPage;
    string outputPdfPath=@"C:/pdf/new.pdf";


    sourceDocument = new Document();
    pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument, new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));

    //Open the output file
    sourceDocument.Open();

    try
    {
        //Loop through the files list
        for (int f = 0; f < lstFiles.Length-1; f++)
        {
            int pages =get_pageCcount(lstFiles[f]);

            reader = new PdfReader(lstFiles[f]);
            //Add pages of current file
            for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
            {
                importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
            }

            reader.Close();
         }
        //At the end save the output file
        sourceDocument.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }


private int get_pageCcount(string file)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(file)))
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(sr.ReadToEnd());

        return matches.Count;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The reference that you need is

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

Comment: Don't tell us what references out of iTextSharp we might need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a free open source lib using pdftk under the hood

```cs
var pdftk = new PDFtk();

var result = await pdftk.ConcatAsync(new[]
{
    await File.ReadAllBytesAsync("Pdf1.pdf"),
    await File.ReadAllBytesAsync("Pdf2.pdf")
});

if(result.Success)
{
   // Do something with result.Result (bytes[])
}
```

https://github.com/kevbite/Kevsoft.PDFtk#concatenate-multiple-pdfs